# Optimization for functions that produce NaN for some initial values

Tags: r, optimization, nan, arbitrary-precision

I would like to find all local minimums of the following objective function

```
func <- function(b){Mat=matrix(c(+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2,+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2,+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2,+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2),2,2);d=(det(Mat));return(d)}
```

'func' is determinant of Fisher information matrix of Logistic regression model and is a
function of parameters b1 and b2 where b1 belongs to [-.3, .3] and b2 to [6, 8]

Suppose these two initial values for b = c(b1, b2)

```
> in1 <- c(-0.04785405, 6.42711047)
> in2 <- c(0.2246729, 7.5211575)
```

The local minimum with initial value `in1` is:

```
> optim(in1, fn = func, lower = c(-.3, 6), upper = c(.3, 8), method = "L-BFGS-B")

$par
[1] -0.04785405  6.42711047

$value
[1] 3.07185e-27

$counts
function gradient 
   1        1 

$convergence
[1] 52

$message
[1] "ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH"
```

As can be seen in the `$massage` a termination happened in optimization process and minimum could not be computed and `optim` returned  `in1` as local optima.

For 'in2' also  an error is appeared:

```
> optim(in2, fn = func, lower = c(-.3, 6), upper = c(.3, 8), method = "L-BFGS-B")

Error in optim(in2, fn = func, lower = c(-0.3, 6), upper = c(0.3, 8),  : 
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

This error happened because the value of `func` for `in2' is`NaN`:

```
> func(in2)
[1] NaN
```

However for `in1` the value of objective function at `in1` is calculated but the optimization is terminated because `optim` could not continue the calculation for another 
intial values:

```
> func(in1)
[1] 3.07185e-27
```

Let me define func without det and just as matrix to see what happened:

```
Mat.func <- function(b){Mat=matrix(c(+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2,+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2,+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5)/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2,+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*-5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) * -5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-b[1]-b[2]*5)+1))))*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) * 5/(exp(-b[1] - b[2] * 5) + 1)^2),2,2);d=Mat;return(d)}
```

We get

```
         > Mat.func(in1)
              [,1]         [,2]
         [1,] 1.109883e-14 2.784007e-15
         [2,] 2.784007e-15 2.774708e-13

        > Mat.func(in2)
              [,1] [,2]
          [1,]  Inf  Inf
          [2,]  Inf  Inf
```

Hence, by double precision, values of `Mat.func(in2)` elements are `Inf`.
I also rewrite `Mat.func` with mpfr function:

```
Mat.func.mpfr <-function(b, prec){ d=c(+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2,
                                   +0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) * -5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) * 5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2,
                                   +0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) * -5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5)/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) * 5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2,
                                   +0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*-5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) * -5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) * -5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * -5) + 1)^2+0.5*1/((1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))*(1-(1/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec)-mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec)*5)+1))))*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) * 5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2*exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) * 5/(exp(-mpfr(b[1], precBits = prec) - mpfr(b[2], precBits = prec) * 5) + 1)^2)
                               Mat = new("mpfrMatrix", d, Dim = c(2L, 2L))
                               return(Mat)}
```

Thus:

```
require(Rmpfr)
> Mat.func.mpfr(c(in1), prec = 54)
'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (2, 2) of precision  54   bits 
     [,1]                   
 [1,] 1.10988301365972506e-14
 [2,] 2.78400749725484580e-15
      [,2]                   
 [1,] 2.78400749725484580e-15
 [2,] 2.77470753414931256e-13

 > Mat.func.mpfr(c(in2), prec = 54)
 'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (2, 2) of precision  54   bits 
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  Inf  Inf
 [2,]  Inf  Inf

 > Mat.func.mpfr(c(in2), prec = 55)
 'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (2, 2) of precision  55   bits 
      [,1]                    
 [1,]  4.16032108702067276e-17
 [2,] -8.34300174643550123e-17
      [,2]                    
 [1,] -8.34300174643550154e-17
 [2,]  1.04008027175516816e-15
```

So by precision 55 the values of matrix elements are not `Inf` anymore. unfortunately,
`mpfr` function changes the class of an objective and nor `det` neither r optimization functions can not be applied, to clarify I provide two examples:

```
> class(mpfr (1/3, 54))
[1] "mpfr"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Rmpfr"

## determinant
example1 <- function(x){
  d <- c(mpfr(x, prec = 54), 3 * mpfr(x, prec = 54), 5 * mpfr(x, prec = 54), 7 * mpfr(x, prec = 54))
  Mat = new("mpfrMatrix", d, Dim = c(2L, 2L))
  return(det(Mat))
}

> example1(2)
Error in UseMethod("determinant") : 
no applicable method for 'determinant' applied to an object of class "c('mpfrMatrix',    'mpfrArray', 'Mnumber', 'mNumber', 'mpfr', 'list', 'vector')"

##optimization 
example2 <- function(x)  ## Rosenbrock Banana function
   100 * (mpfr(x[2], prec = 54) - mpfr(x[1], prec = 54) * mpfr(x[1], prec = 54 ))^2 + (1 - mpfr(x[1], prec = 54))^2

> example2(c(-1.2, 1))
1 'mpfr' number of precision  54   bits 
[1] 24.1999999999999957
> optim(c(-1.2,1), example2)
Error in optim(c(-1.2, 1), example2) : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Hence, using mpfr could not solve the problem.

To find All the local minimums,  an algorithm which applies different **random** initial values should be written.
But as can be seen, for some initial values the function produces `NaN`
(ignorance of these values  would not be a good idea because it may generally results in missing some local minimums ,specially for functions that have lots of local optima).

I was wondering if there is any R package that can carry on optimization process with **arbitrary precision** to avoid `NaN` for objective functions?

Thank you

Comment: you might be able to reformulate your objective function to get fewer `NaN` values (e.g. by rearranging to minimize the possibility of underflow/overflow)

Comment: So you are trying to minimize `log(det(some_matrix))`. 1) You get NaN whenever `det(some_matrix) < 0` because `log(x)` is not defined for `x < 0`; what meaning do you give to that? 2) The optimizer will try to find where `det(some_matrix) == 0`; maybe changing your objective to `abs(det(some_matrix))` will fix the asymptotic behavior. It's hard to say what you are trying to do.

Comment: @flodel actually I tried it without log, but the answer was same. sorry the value of func(in1) and func(in2) that I wrote in the question are for det(some_matrix) and not log(det(some_matrix)) I removed log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think **the** answer (I think 'agstudy' gave, too) is:
Make sure that the function you minimize does *NOT* return NaN (or NA) but rather +Inf (if you minimize, or 
-Inf if you maximize).

2nd: Instead of  log(det(.))  you *REALLY* should use
 {
  r <- determinant(., log=TRUE) ;
  if(r$sign <= 0) -Inf else r$modulus
 }

which is also more accurate.  {Hint: do look how  det is defined in R !}

Now to Rmpfr, I will reply separately.  It *should* work like standard R to use "mpfr"-numbers,
.... says the author of Rmpfr ....
but you may need a bit of care.
tryCatch() should not be needed, however.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reformulate your horrible(sorry for the term)  objective function. I am pretty sure that w we can find with simpler form. Hope that others can use this to find a solution to your optimization problem...

```
func1 <- function(b){
  A <- exp(-b[1]+5*b[2])
  C <- exp(-b[1]-5*b[2])
  A1 <- A + 1
  C1 <- C + 1
  D <- 1/A1
  H <- 1/C1
  K <- D*(1-D)
  J <- H*(1-H)
  M <- (A/A1^2)^2/K
  N <- (C/C1^2)^2/J


Mat <- matrix(c( 1 *M    + 1  *N,
                -5 *M    + 5  *N,
                -5 *M    + 5  *N,
                25 *M    + 25 *N),2,2)

  Mat <- 0.5*Mat
  d <- log(det(Mat))
  return(d)
}
```

**EDIT**

As I said you can simplify again your function. It looks much better

```
func1 <- function(b){
  A <- exp(-b[1]+5*b[2])
  C <- exp(-b[1]-5*b[2])
  A1 <- A + 1
  C1 <- C + 1
  M <- A/A1^2
  N <- C/C1^2
  det.Mat <-25*M*N
  log(det.Mat)
}
```

Here some tests between the 2 functions.

```
func1(c(1,2))
[1] -16.7814
> func1(c(8,2))
[1] -17.03498
> func1(c(10,2))
[1] -18.16742
> func(c(10,2))
[1] -18.16742
> func(c(10,5))
[1] -46.83608
```

The reformulation minimized the possibility of underflow/overflow ( can't store the intermediate result in the register)..that's why we get Inf and not NA(see below) , which is infinite but still a **numeric**, suitable for farther computing in opposition to NaN which is like an NA values..

> func(c(10,100))
>       [1] NaN
>   func1(c(10,100))
>       [1] -Inf

Now I test your optimization instruction, on the simpler form , and it converges as you can see:

```
in1 <- c(-0.04785405, 6.42711047)
in2 <- c(0.2246729, 7.5211575)
ll <- optim(in1, fn = func1, lower = c(-.3, 6), upper = c(.3, 8), method = "L-BFGS-B")
 do.call(rbind,ll)


            function                                           gradient                                          
par         "-0.04785405"                                      "8"                                               
value       "-76.7811241751318"                                "-76.7811241751318"                               
counts      "2"                                                "2"                                               
convergence "0"                                                "0"                                               
message     "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL" "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

same thing for in2

```
optim(in2, fn = func1, lower = c(-.3, 6), upper = c(.3, 8), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 0.2246729 8.0000000

$value
[1] -76.78112

$counts
function gradient 
       2        2 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

Comment: I agree that the formulate of my function is horrible and thank you for your modification.
 actually, I did not write it!! in fact I applied  functions `gsub`, `D`and `paste` to construct the information matrix for all nonlinear models without user-interfere and the formulate that you saw is auto-constructed.

Comment: @EhsanMasoudi ok but when you ask an answer here you have to do more effort..or at least give us how you have do to have such function...That 's said I update my answer for more simple function.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain why func(c(10, 100)) is "Nan" but func(c(10, 100)) is `-Inf'

Comment: I add some explanation...It is my interpretation of things..I am not a numeric specialist..

Answer (score 2):

Answering your problem, using the `Rmpfr` - produced matrix:
(not quite efficiently though ...!...):

Yes, determinant() is not available for mpfr-matrices,
*however* you can simply use something like

```
M <- Mat.func.mpfr(in2, prec = 55)
m <- as(M, "matrix")
ldm <- determinant(m) # is already  log() !
```

and then use the

```
 { r <- determinant(., log=TRUE) ; if(r$sign <= 0) -Inf else r$modulus }
```

I've mentioned above ... something much better than the  ``wrong by design'' use of   log(det(.))

Answer (score 1):

For arb precision:  `gmp` and / or `Rmpfr` .
You might be better off with some `tryCatch` in your code instead, though (to avoid crashes when a given attempt causes that `NaN` error)

Comment: I edited the question with Rmpfr and as can be seen it could not be useful. Also, as i said ignoring NaN by tryCathch may leads to missing some local minimums.

Comment: arb precision = arbitrary precision or precision in arb library ?

Comment: @Adam  "arbitrary"  ... at the time I posted this I wasn't even aware of an `arb` package.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mpfr` can be useful to avoid computationally `NaN` in a function (and also halt in optimization algorithm). But 
`mpfr` output is an 'mpfr' class and some R functions (such as `optim` and `det`) may not work with this kind of class. 
As usual  `as.numeric` can be applied to convert 'mpfr' class to a 'numeric' one.

```
exp(9000)
[1] Inf

require(Rmpfr)
number <- as.numeric(exp(mpfr(9000, prec = 54)))

class(number)
[1] "numeric"

round(number)
[1] 1.797693e+308

number * 1.797692e-308
[1] 3.231699

number * 1.797693e-307
[1] 32.317

number * (1/number)
[1] 1

number * .2
[1] 3.595386e+307

number * .9
[1] 1.617924e+308

number * 1.1
[1] Inf

number * 2
[1] Inf

number / 2
[1] 8.988466e+307

number + 2
[1] 1.797693e+308

number + 2 * 10 ^ 291
[1] 1.797693e+308

number + 2 * 10 ^ 292
[1] Inf

number - 2
[1] 1.797693e+308

number - 2 * 10 ^ 307
[1] 1.597693e+308

number - 2 * 10 ^ 308
[1] -Inf
```

Now consider the following matrix function:

```
mat <- function(x){
x1 <- x[1]
x2 <- x[2]
d = matrix(c(exp(5 * x1+ 4 * x2), exp(9 * x1), exp(2 * x2 + 4 * x1),
           exp(3 * x1)), 2, 2)
         return(d)
}
```

elements of this matrix is highly potential to produce `Inf`:

```
mat(c(300, 1))
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]  Inf  Inf
[2,]  Inf  Inf
```

So if  `det` was returned in function environment, instead of a numeric result we  got `NaN` and the `optim` function would definitely be terminated. To solve this problem the determinant of this function is written by `mpfr`:

```
func <- function (x){
  x1 <- mpfr(x[1], prec = precision)
  x2 <- mpfr(x[2], prec = precision)
  mat <- new("mpfrMatrix",c(exp(5 * x1+ 4 * x2), exp(9 * x1), exp(2 * x2 + 4 * x1),   exp(3 * x1)), Dim = c(2L,2L))
  d <- mat[1, 1] * mat[2, 2] - mat[2, 1] * mat[1, 2]
  return(as.numeric(-d))
}
```

then for x1 = 3 and x2 =  1  we have:

```
func(c(3,1))
[1] 6.39842e+17

optim(c(3, 1),func)

$par
[1] 0.4500 1.4125

$value
[1] -4549.866

$counts
function gradient 
  13       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

and for x1 = 300 and x2 = 1:

```
func(c(300,1))
[1] 1.797693e+308

optim(c(300, 1),func)
$par
[1] 300   1

$value
[1] 1.797693e+308

$counts
function gradient 
   3       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

As can bee seen, there is no halt and even `optim` claimes a convergence in the optimization process. However, it seems that there are no iterations and `optim` just returned the initial values as local minimums (definitely, 1.797693e+308 is not a local minimum of this function!!). 
In such these situations, applying `mpfr` can just prevent termination of optimization process,
but if we really expect  optimization algorithm to start from such this points which their values are `Inf` by R double-precision and continue the iteration to reach the local minimums, besides defining a function with 'mpfr' class, the optimization function also should have this ability to work with 'mpfr' class.

Comment: Feel free to write an add-on package that does this. One difficulty is that most of R's optimizers use lower-level (C or FORTRAN) code internally, which will not easily be adaptable to using `mfpr`.  One thought would be that you could try some of the optimizers in the `optimx` package, which have "pure-R" versions of conjugate gradient and quasi-Newton methods which might work `mfpr` objects.

Comment: @Ben Bolker actually I would like to write this package and I also have chosen an appropriate package called Rsolnp which is pure-R and is based on a Matlab code.